# Getting/Parsing ShoutCast Metadata

Tags: c#, shoutcast, bass

I currently making simple music player and would like to stream online radio. I managed to stream ShoutCast radio but the problem is I have no idea how to parse the title and artist from streaming metadata. Here is my code.

**Player.cs**

```
    public string[] GetTags(bool streaming)
    {
        if (streaming == true)
        {
            IntPtr tag = Bass.BASS_ChannelGetTags(stream, BASSTag.BASS_TAG_META);
            string[] tags = Utils.IntPtrToArrayNullTermUtf8(tag);
            if (tags != null)
            {
                return tags;
            }            
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Main.cs**

```
  private void btnLoadURL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p.LoadURL(tbFile.Text);
        string[] tags = p.GetTags(true);
        if (tags != null) 
        {
            foreach (String tag in tags)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = tag;
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently I need to iterate through the `tags` to get the metadata in the format `StreamTitle='xxx';StreamUrl='xxx';`. I would like to parse this into;

Title: xxx

Artist: xxx

and remove `StreamUrl` entirely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My own approach is to concatenate an array of strings into a string using `String.Join` method

```
string conTitle = String.Join("", tags);
```

then by using regular expression I am able to extract artist and song from the string:

```
if (tags != null)
            {
                string ConTitle = String.Join("", tags);
                string FullTitle = Regex.Match(ConTitle,
                  "(StreamTitle=')(.*)(';StreamUrl)").Groups[2].Value.Trim();
                string[] Title = Regex.Split(FullTitle, " - ");
                return Title;
            }
```

In **Main.cs** I iterate the returned value and assign the variable according to the string[] index

```
if (tags != null) 
        {
            foreach (string tag in tags)
            {
                lblArtist.Text = tags[0];
                lblTitle.Text = tags[1];
            }
        }
```

<s>[Here's the player image since I don't have enough rep yet to upload one](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2daja8l.jpg)</s>
[image: I have enough rep now, so here's the image.]

Though I have to look into the regex back since album title also appeared there.

**EDIT**: Here's the modified regex:

```
Regex.Match(ConTitle, "(StreamTitle=')(.*)(\\(.*\\)';StreamUrl)").Groups[2].Value.Trim();
```

Now no more bracket with album title after song title.

Comment: Just beware that the `StreamTitle` value isn't always in the format of `Artist - Title`.  This is just a convention often followed, but often not.  I would guess that it works around 70% of the time, but not higher.

Comment: Yeah you are right, guess I should find a way to parse them regardless of format they are on. Thanks for the heads up!